# replaceFirst in Groovy throws Illegal group reference

Tags: regex, groovy

I have the following code:

```
String newStr = "aa\$";
print newStr;
print "wwwww ? eeee".replaceFirst("\\?", "'${newStr}'"); // (3)
```

and I keep getting -- at line 3 -- the following error:

```
Caught: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal group reference
    at com.example.MyBuilder.main(MyBuilder.groovy:196)
```

It looks like that *replaceFirst* ignores that $ was escaped. How could I let my code run? Does anybody experience such an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a working solution for my problem: `String newStr == "aa\\\$";` 
You need to have three backslashes. The first backslash (from right to left) escapes $ so Groovy Interpreter does not understand $ as a mark for a variable.

The two following slashes has to escape $ for [replaceFirst](http://veerasundar.com/blog/2010/01/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-illegal-group-reference-in-string-replaceall/), because $ is interpreted by *[Matcher.appendReplacement()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement%28java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String%29)*  -- called inside replaceFirst -- as a *grouping*. It is an unexpected but [well documented in JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) behavior:

> backslashes (\) and dollar signs ($)  in the
>   replacement string may cause the
>   results to be different than if it
>   were being treated as a literal
>   replacement string

ps. After fighting with escaping other "special" symbol -- backslash -- I switched to [String.replace(CharSequence,CharSequence)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29).

Comment: So does `newStr = /aa\$/` not do it then?

Comment: I do not know why but my groovy eclipse plugin does not like // syntax so I do not know if it works.

Comment: I guess you need a better/newer plugin

Comment: That's not a bug in `replaceFirst()`, it's working exactly as specified.  Matcher also provides a `quoteReplacement()` method that escapes dollar signs and backslashes for you.

Answer (score 6):

First

```
String newStr == "aa\$"
```

should be

```
String newStr = "aa\$"
```

Then, because you are using normal strings to declare your regex, you need to double escape the dollar sign:

```
String newStr = "aa\\$"
```

Or, use slashy strings:

```
String newStr = /aa\$/
```

Comment: And obviously you Mr. Tim_yates ready for helping others in their Groovy doubts :):)